# Codeigniter session is not saving userdata and creating duplicate sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, session, session-cookies

I'm trying to send my *username* and *password* via AJAX to the database for verifying the user but I see CI is creating duplicate sessions for a single request. Also when I'm trying to set the `userdata` through `session->set_userdata` it is not setting the data. This is confirmed as neither firebug nor my session database shows the data. Also since no data is getting set in the session I do not get anything back in my AJAX response to show in the AJAX response success

Please guide me what am I doing wrong here as the session cookies are created even if the *username* and *password* combination is wrong.

Model:

```
function validate_login()
{
    $this->db->where('Useremail',$this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('Password',$this->input->post('password'));
    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
function validate_login_user()
{
    $this->load->model('data_model');

    if ($this->data_model->validate_login())
    {
        $data = array (
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return = $this->session->userdata('username');
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<script>

    $(function() {

        $('.login').click(function(){
            var username = $('#username').attr('value');
            var password = $('#password').attr('value');
            if (username == "" || password == ""){
                $('.LoginErrormsg').css('display','block');
            }
            if (username !== "" && password !== ""){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo site_url('home/validate_login_user');?>",
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{username:username,
                        password:password},
                    success:function(){
                        $('#sitelogin').html(msg);
                        $('.logout').css('display','block');
                    }
                });
                return false
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
    })

</script>

<div id="sitelogin">
    <input type="text" class="loginbox" name = "login_username" id = "username" placeholder="Email address / Username" />
    <input type="password" class="loginbox" name = "login_password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <div class="LoginErrormsg">You forgot to enter Username and Password</div>
        <button class="login" name = "login">Login</button>
        <button class="logout" name = "logout">Logout</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the session data immediately after setting it, Codeigniter's session are actually cookies and its available only of page reloads.. read more [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: I cleared all cookies and then clicked the login button and I immediately find the session cookie set in the firebug XHR console. Even the session database shows a session logged in with duplicate session ids. I'm really surprised why my session data doesn't load into the session cookie.

The ajax request is sent to the validation script with status 200 OK. The most disturbing fact is that the session gets created even if the credentials are not validated.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this **you have to reload the page** using php or AJAX.

If php you can use `redirect()` when success. so it will not come back to AJAX.

If AJAX use `window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/method");`